# Can not archive the app associated with Zbar sdk in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

I have developed an application where i used the zbar sdk. It was working well in xcode 4.5, but recently i have updated to xcode 5. Now when i want to archive my app for app store, it shows the following error.

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/codemenmini2012-2/Desktop/QRTime (Zbar)/libzbar.a file '/Users/codemenmini2012-2/Desktop/QRTime (Zbar)/libzbar.a' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to solve the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

remove armv7s from valid architecture in project targets.